# Sanitisation on user input using whitelist

Tags: php, sanitization, whitelist

I have this code which sanitises user input on a variable called 'username':

```
$username_clean = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $_POST['username'] );

if (!strlen($username_clean)){

die("username is blank!");
```

I want to carry out the same process on each input on this page but I have about 12 different inputs since it is a registering form. Is there an easier way to sanitise and check each input instead of applying preg_replace() and the if statement on each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sanitize all of the elements in `$_POST`, then you could just create a sanitization function and apply it to all the elements with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$post_clean = array_map("sanitization_function", $_POST);
```

Then you'd access your variables via `$post_clean` instead of `$_POST`.

It'd look something like:

```
function sanitize($dirty){ 
    return preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $dirty ); 
}

$cPOST = array_map("sanitize", $_POST);

if (!strlen($cPOST['username'])){ 
    die("username is blank!"); 
}
```

If you only wanted to sanitize a subset of the `$_POST` elements, you could do something like:

```
$cPOST = array();
$sanitize_keys = array('username','someotherkeytosanitize');
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(in_array($k, $sanitize_keys))
    {
        $cPOST[$k] = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $v);
    }
    else
    {
        $cPOST[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

---

Try this:

```
$cPOST = array();
$sanitize_keys = array('username','someotherkeytosanitize');
for($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(in_array($k, $sanitize_keys))
    {
        $cPOST[$k] = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $v);
        if(strlen($cPOST[$k]) == 0){ 
            die("%s is blank", $k);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $cPOST[$k] = $v;
    }
}
# At this point, the variables in $cPOST are the same as $_POST, unless you 
# specified they be sanitized (by including them in the $sanitize_keys array.
# Also, if you get here, you know that the entries $cPOST that correspond
# to the keys in $sanitize_keys were not blank after sanitization.
```

Just make sure to change $sanitize_keys to an array of whatever variables (or $_POST keys) you want to sanitize.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean I still need to apply the if statement to each input?

Comment: @user: Yes you would.  Do you want the script to "die()" if any of the elements are empty?

Comment: Extending first portion of this answer, you can run the `$cPOST` variable through `array_filter($input, $callback)` function where your callback returns `true` for empty array element. You can then check the `count()` of the returned array, and `array_keys()` to display name of fields in error.

Comment: @jedwards: I am getting this error using your coding:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting ';' in

Comment: change for to foreach -- sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

If the regex and test for failure is the same, you can write a function:

```
function validate($input, $input_name) {
  $clean_input = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $input );
  if (!strlen($username_clean)){
    die("$input_name is blank!");
  }
  return $clean_input;
}
validate($_POST['username'], "Username");
```

Comment: Thanks but how is this applied to each input? such as $password $first_name etc

Comment: You have to validate each of these inputs. So it would be a call to validate($password, "Password"); for password, etc. Or you can use array_map to apply it to each thing in your POST array, as indicated in another response.