# Inserting Google Profile ID MYSQL via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm new to Javascript and PHP, but I have been able to setup a simple web app at www.gearedwebdesigns.com/BPHCalcEnter.php I want to be able to also insert the google Id token into my database alongside with the 2 number inputs on the site. That way each record will belong to a specific google ID. Please correct me if this is horribly wrong.

The problem that I face now is that I am doing database inserts and deletes right now on a different php file. www.gearedwebdesigns.com/BPHTable.php but this redirects back to BPHCalcEnter.php so is it possible to insert the Google ID token the same way I am inserting right now? I'm not too sure how to access a javascript variable via php

Here's the external javascript I use to set the variables from the Google Sign in.

```
   function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // Used to display in HTML 
    document.getElementById("gName").innerHTML = profile.getName();
    document.getElementById("gPic").src = profile.getImageUrl();

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  };
```

And here's my BPHTable.php code. I'm sure a lot can be improved here too. Please criticize away.

```
 <?php header("Location: http://www.gearedwebdesigns.com/BPHCalcEnter.php");?>  
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>

 </head>
<body>

    <?php

    // Define MySQL connection and credentials
    $pdo_dsn='mysql:dbname=gearedwe_ODFLtest;host=localhost';
    $pdo_user='gearedwe_admin';     
    $pdo_password='dbtest';  

    // Check that user sent some data to begin with. 
    if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_REQUEST['yourfield'])&& isset($_REQUEST['hoursWorked']))   {          

 // Establish connection to database
    $conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","gearedwe_admin","dbtest","gearedwe_ODFLtest");

    // Throw exceptions in case of error.
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /* Sanitize input. Trust *nothing* sent by the client.
     * When possible use whitelisting, only allow characters that you know
     * are needed. If username must contain only alphanumeric characters,
     * without puntation, then you should not accept anything else.
     * For more details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10094315
     */
    $yourfield=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/','',$_REQUEST['yourfield']);
    $hoursWorked=$_REQUEST['hoursWorked'];

    /* Escape your input: use htmlspecialchars to avoid most obvious XSS attacks.
     * Note: Your application may still be vulnerable to XSS if you use $yourfield
     *       in an attribute without proper quoting.
     * For more details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/130323
     */
    $yourfield=htmlspecialchars($yourfield);
    $hoursWorked=htmlspecialchars($hoursWorked);
    try {
    // Establish connection to database
    $conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","gearedwe_admin","dbtest","gearedwe_ODFLtest");

    // Throw exceptions in case of error.
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Use prepared statements to mitigate SQL injection attacks.
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for more details

    $qry=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `gearedwe_ODFLtest`.`yourtable` ( `billsEntered`, `dateEntered`, `hoursWorked`, `BPH`) VALUES ( :yourvalue, CURRENT_DATE(), $hoursWorked, `billsEntered`/$hoursWorked);");



    // Execute the prepared statement using user supplied data.
    $qry->execute(Array(":yourvalue" => $yourfield));

     mysqli_close($con);

} 


    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
    exit;
}
}


    else {
   die('User did not send any data to be saved!');

    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ probably...

Comment: Your test database pass is on the $con = line.  You may want to change that as it will be in the stackoverflow edit history if you edit it out of this post.

Comment: Wow, yeah I didn't even think of that. Haha, been a long day. Thanks.